# In Spring Boot Eureka Client How does eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone work and how to add new eureka server?

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

By default the property `eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone` value is `http://localhost:8761/eureka`.
However I noticed that directly accessing this url returns 404. But `http://localhost:8761` loads eureka dashboard. Then how does a eureka client gets registered with eureka server, does it internally accesses only the host name, and path `/eureka` is there for semantic purpose only?

Since `eureka.client.service-url`is a map, would like to know how to register another eureka server which is not a `defaultZone`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/eureka` is an actual path prefix. It returns a 404 error because it is not defined as a valid path on its own. Specific service paths are built from that prefix, e.g. `/eureka/apps/yourapp1`.

About using multiple zones, this may help:

```
eureka:
  client:
    region: region-1
    service-url:
      zone1: http://eureka01.foo:8761/eureka/
      zone2: http://eureka02.foo:8761/eureka/
    availability-zones:
      region-1: zone1,zone2
```